# Long silent delay before Honda Accord 2003 cranks

Tags: honda, starting, accord

I have a Honda Accord 2003 car. I have been having an odd problem lately, and I'm not sure what the cause of it is.

Generally in the mornings when I go to start the car, it takes several seconds to start after turning the key. If I hold the key down, it will eventually start, but it takes sometimes up to 5 seconds of holding the key down. There is complete silence, and once the engine starts, it sounds completely normal. It never makes a sound like its trying and failing to start.

It has only been happening bad in the morning. 8.5 hours later when I go home, it starts up after just a brief 1-2 second delay. Then again the next morning, there is a long delay.

This has been happening a couple of weeks. The only thing it has corresponded to is the oncoming summer heat (I'm in SE Tennessee). Is this a battery problem, a starter problem, or something else?

Comment: Are you saying it cranks but won't start for the 5 or so seconds, or that it does absolutely nothing for the 5 seconds (no crank/no start)?

Comment: @Paulster2 absolutely nothing as far as I an tell during that 5 seconds (silent), but it will start after the delay if I persist in holding down the key.

Comment: This is a new one on me. Maybe someone else has a clue.

Comment: Is this an intermittent issue (happens every morning or just some mornings)?

Comment: It had been rather intermittent for a few weeks, but for about the past week it has been a daily issue.

Comment: Hmmm, seems like an issue with the [starter](http://www.driveaccord.net/forums/15-7th-generation/53959-04-accord-wont-start-its-not-battery.html). What's puzzling is that you're able to get it to start after a few seconds, almost as if some part of the circuitry warms up enough to make sustained contact. You might want to check your starter relay and wiring before declaring the starter kaput.

Comment: I'll look into that. I was assuming/hoping it wouldn't be the starter as it was replaced only about two years ago.

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there was a recall for the ignition switch on your car. My 2002 Civic had this same problem, and that was the component causing the issue.

TLDR: Inspect/replace the ignition switch.