# Replacing Starter Relay on Honda Accord 2003

Tags: honda, starting, accord, relay

In having [this issue](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17599/long-silent-delay-before-honda-accord-2003-cranks), I am trying to figure out how to find and replace my starter relay in a Honda Accord 2003.

Where is the starter relay? How can it be replaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relay is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpvi2.png):

[image]

That's in the driver's footwell. I believe it's above the fuse box, around the hood open latch. There's a plastic cover over the relays you'll have to pull off. There's one for the relays and one for the fuse box.

It should just pull out and the new one can be popped right in. You'll have to pull hard.

Answer (score 0):

Some cars also have a fuse box or relay box and sometimes a combination of the two under the hood. As well as, They're usually identified in the cover. Remember to check under the foot well inside the car also.

Answer (score 0):

Starter Motor allows the engine to "start" and begin running. While, a faulty starter will result in a difficulty in starting the engine.It is frustrating when your car won't start. You are turning the key and... nothing happens. Maybe [this article guide](https://www.hexautoparts.com/blog/post/How-To-Repair-2003-2007-Honda-CRV-Honda-Accord-Starter-2.4L-Replacement-Guide.html) would help you

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the starter relay is above the inside fuse box.  The inside fuse box is under the dash, located to the left of the driver's footrest.  The fuse box has a nice, sliding cover.

However, the relays do not have a nice door.  You have to pull off the plastic piece that surrounds the fuse box.  This panel is held on by fasteners (no screws) that I simply yanked on until it came off.  The plastic floor moulding goes over the piece you want to remove, so you will have to finagle it a bit so that the moulding releases the panel.